# How to access app on Dokku when it's deployed on dokku-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01?

Tags: dokku

I'm very new to Dokku and I managed to deploy my Django app on Dokku on Digital Ocean. But it says

```
Application deployed:
http://dokku-ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01
```

How am I gonna access to that?

Answer (score 2):

That "domain" is actually the internal hostname for your server. Dokku will pull that in automatically if you did not properly setup your server by going to the associated domain or IP for your server and filling out the form with the proper values.

I would suggest either changing the global domain on the server (`domains:set-global`) or setting the domains on the app (`domains:set`). You can alternatively disable domains for your app and then redeploy your app, at which point a random (persistent throughout deploys!) port will be associated and you can browse to your app at `http://$SERVER_IP:$APP_PORT`.